# Magento layered navigation, select multiple filters via URL

Tags: layered-navigation

we use layered navigation. And we also used to send filter links in newsletters Like URL/?shirt_size=8 ....

But recently we have come across the need to filter both on shirt_size=8 and shirt_size=12 in one link .....

**Question: can this be done in Magento. And if so how?**

ps. This did not work
?shirt_size=8,12
?shirt_size=6&shirt_size=8
?shirt_size=6;8

Comment: the current layered navigation uses AND when filtering the collection instead of OR, you can make a custom function to do this see here how to do this: https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

Comment: Only one filter selection per attribute is allowed natively.